# ActionDispatch::Request::Session keeps giving the following error: *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, null, actiondispatch

I am trying to set some attributes in a before_action of a store with multi step checkout behaviour.

All the before_action does is set some attributes for session

`session[:checkout_attributes] ||= {}`

but after the first step I keep getting the following error.

`<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x11f80 not yet loaded> *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method` key?' for nil:NilClass`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I tried force loading the session using `session.send(:load!)` but it did not help, it just gave the same error.

Comment: It would help if you added more detail to your question and some actual code sample than just the one line that is getting the error. Also a stack trace would help.